# How do I include javax.servlet servlet-api 3.0.1 in my Maven project?

Tags: spring, maven, jar, dependencies, javax

I'm using Maven 3.3.  Do I need to add any special repositories to access the servlet-api 3.0.1 jar?  I've added this to my pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

but I get this error when I try and do a build ...

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project core: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.collegeboard.springboard:core:jar:99.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:3.0.1 in thirdparty (https://nexus.getmyco.com/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/) -> [Help 1]
```

I need this dependency because I'm told taht anoterh dependency (spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE) requires this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the pom of spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.springframework|spring-test|4.0.6.RELEASE|jar

It actually depends on the following:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Can the scope be set as "provided" ? As I understand, servelet-api is provided by servlet container by default.

Comment: You set the scope the way you want to. This is just a copy-paste from the POM of spring-test, to show you how you can figure out by youself what the dependencies of spring, or any other library, are.